# VueJS, loading attribute dynamic with json object

Tags: json, vue.js, dynamic, loading

I have a problem on my last Vue JS page. I think I am totally wrong.

Let me explain, I have a button which make an API GET call to the backend and I got an array as a response from the API.

When I received this array, I push data in `this.templates`.

I have a v-for on this array **:**

```
<v-flex
      class="pl-5"
      xs12
      md4
      v-for="item of templates"
      :key="item._id"
    >
```

with inside **:**

```
<v-card elevation="10" :loading="loadingTemplates[item._id]">
```

When I received the response, v-card are correctly displayed with loading true. After this, I have a second POST request for each element, and when I received the response, I set to false the value :

```
console.log(`Response for ${element._id} and ${element.loading}`);
this.loadingTemplates[element._id] = false;
```

Log is OK, i have ID and true value.
I set false, but loading is still displayed....

Why ?

Maybe I need to use json object for templates, but i don't know how.
TO resume :
GET Request ==> Get Array with x jobs
POST Request for x jobs ==> With v-simple-table displayed.

Comment: Are you using Vue 2 or Vue 3? Vue 2 has some limitations on reactivity when it comes to arrays so it won't realize that you updated the array the way you are trying to do it.

Comment: It would be nice, to see a bit more details about your problem. Please see how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise it is not easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `@stellr42` mentioned in his comment, Vue 2 has some limitations on reactivity when it comes to arrays. You can have a look into this official [`documentation`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array **:**

- When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `this.loadingTemplates[element._id] = false`
- When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `this.loadingTemplates.length = newLength`

Demo as per the above statements **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    loadingTemplates: [true, true, false, true]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadingTemplates[1] = false; // Not updating
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item_id in [0, 1, 2, 3]">{{ loadingTemplates[item_id] }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hence, To update and make it reactive - You also have to trigger state updates in the reactivity system.

Working Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    loadingTemplates: [true, true, false, true]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$set(this.loadingTemplates, 1, false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item_id in [0, 1, 2, 3]">{{ loadingTemplates[item_id] }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I add this line, with my element ID. And it solved all my problem. Loading stopped, and data table are correctly displayed now ! Does i understand, this.$set refresh everything ? But should i conclude i should use json child item versus an array ?

Comment: @user3216533 Not everything, It will just update the reactive properties to a nested object/array we passed as a parameter.